# Select distinct and the most recent one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get most recent bahis.ID and bahis.isim field witch has a JOIN rule. But in this one I'm getting same bahis.IDs and bahis.isims. I want to get their most recent one and then continue.

I tried so many, but all of them failed somehow. This is my last recent query;

```
SELECT bahis.ID, bahis.isim 
FROM bahis 
JOIN yorumbahis 
  ON yorumbahis.bahisid = bahis.ID 
ORDER BY yorumbahis.ID DESC LIMIT 0,12
```

Simply, how do I do that?

Result:

```
74 dfgfdggdf5455
68 sdffcc33
68 sdffcc33
76 adsadsd333
76 adsadsd333
74 dfgfdggdf5455
86 hjjk khjjk
73 cdsc4344
63 aaaaxxxxsssxxx
76 adsadsd333
76 adsadsd333
76 adsadsd333
```

Expected result;

```
74 dfgfdggdf5455
68 sdffcc33
76 adsadsd333
86 hjjk khjjk
73 cdsc4344 
63 aaaaxxxxsssxxx
AND CONTINUE...
```

Comment: @Nordenheim and `MIN(bahis.ID)`

Comment: I tried GROUP BY  http://i.hizliresim.com/v58LAA.png

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT bahis.ID, bahis.isim`?

Comment: How do you know which rows that are the most recent ones? I see no timestamp or sequence id.

Comment: Latest yorumbahis.ID is the most recent one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this example

```
CREATE TABLE bets        (`ID` int, `name` varchar(14)); 

INSERT INTO bets (`ID`, `name`) 
VALUES 
(1, 'a'),     (2, 'b'), 
(3, 'c'),     (4, 'd'), 
(5, 'e'); 

CREATE TABLE comments    (`ID` int, `betid` varchar(14)) 
; 

INSERT INTO comments     (`ID`, `betid`) 
VALUES 
(1, '2'),     (2, '2'), 
(3, '3'),     (4, '1'), 
(5, '4'),     (1, '3'), 
(2, '4'),     (3, '1'), 
(4, '2'),     (5, '2');
```

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04f8b6/3)**

```
SELECT b.name, MAX(c.id)
FROM bets b 
JOIN comments c 
ON b.`ID` = c.`betid`
GROUP BY b.name
ORDER BY MAX(c.id) DESC;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| name | MAX(c.id) |
|------|-----------|
|    b |        10 |
|    a |         8 |
|    d |         7 |
|    c |         6 |
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'bahis.ID' in 'field list'

Comment: Updated. At that level the subquery use `T` as alias

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'bahis.isim' in 'group statement'
:(

Comment: Second query is giving the same results as this; http://i.hizliresim.com/v58LAA.png

Comment: Looks like we are just guessing. Create a working sample like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08e5c and get back to us.

Comment: I changed it with T.isim but now the result is `63
aaaaxxxxsssxxx
76
adsadsd333
73
cdsc4344
74
dfgfdggdf5455
86
hjjk khjjk
68
sdffcc33` not the expected again.

Comment: I dont know what you expect, because I dont know the data you use to generate that wrong result. Work a litle bit with me, prepare a working sample and we can solve it right away.

Comment: http://i.hizliresim.com/bDMYJG.jpg this is my data structure in English. I want to get 12 bet names with latest comments. I only want distinct names. If there s double or more comment on a bet, I want to get that bet's name only once. In an order by comments' ID or comments' date. (which are same)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105385/discussion-between-ece-and-juan-carlos-oropeza).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT bahis.ID, max(bahis.isim) 
FROM bahis 
JOIN yorumbahis 
  ON yorumbahis.bahisid = bahis.ID 
group by bahis.id
ORDER BY yorumbahis.ID DESC LIMIT 0,12
```

Comment: please post your table structure

Comment: i.hizliresim.com/bDMYJG.jpg this is my data structure in English. I want to get 12 bet names with latest comments. I only want distinct names. If there s double or more comment on a bet, I want to get that bet's name only once. In an order by comments' ID or comments' date. (which are same)